# Можно ли как-то сделать так чтобы скрипт срабатывал не после двух нажатий или одного, а целой комбинации? AHK

Tags: autohotkey

Вот есть скрипт который должен сработать после нажатия клавиши. Но мне нужно чтобы он работал после комбинации клавиш. К примеру: g+h+t+5+8+i (как на кодовом замке сейфа). Можно ли это как-то реализовать? Мб подскажите как это называется?)
Облазил инет + англоязычный и ничего полезного не нашёл. А может такого вовсе и нет? Подскажите плиз)

Answer (score 1):

> Этот пример на JavaScript предназначен только для демонстрации и понимания алгоритма. Логика скрипта проста, и реализация на других языках не должна вызвать затруднений.

Если код вводится последовательным одиночным нажатием клавиш, то будет как-то так:

```js
// Валидная комбинация
var sSecretCode = 'ght58i';
// Вводимая комбинация
var sInputCode = '';
(function() {
  /* "Слушаем" клавиатуру */
  window.addEventListener('keydown', function(ev) {
    // Добавляем символ нажатой клавиши в конец вводимой комбинации
    sInputCode = sInputCode + ev.key;
    // Если символы в заданной позиции совпадают, тогда...
    if (sInputCode[sInputCode.length - 1] === sSecretCode[sInputCode.length - 1]) {
      // Если обе комбинации полностью совпали, тогда...
      if (sInputCode === sSecretCode) {
        // Выполняем нужный скрипт
        console.log("Отлично! Запускаем скрипт.");
        // Сбрасываем введённую комбинацию
        sInputCode = '';
      }
    // ... иначе...
    } else {
      // Сбрасываем введённую комбинацию
      sInputCode = '';
    }
    // Отображаем текущий набор (для наглядности)
    console.log("Текущая набранная комбинация: ", sInputCode);
  }, false);
})()
```

При любой ошибке ввода, нужно набирать код сначала.